# How to enable mouse input in raspberry pi

Tags: raspbian, raspi-config

I connected a tft touch lcd display with my raspberry pi and now i cannot control my cursor with my usb mouse. Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If this is a display that connects via GPIO pins, please make sure that you have installed the correct touch driver. If the displays' touch interface connects with usb, it would work out of the box. If the display connects using the SPI connector (raspberry pi brand displays), it would work right away or it is broken.

Comment: The touch interface works fine , but it somehow disabled my mouse-cursor interface ( so now i can’t control my cursor with my usb mouse, and I don’t want to use touch interface for my current project)

Comment: in the case that you disabled mouse cursor interface, you may want to reinstall your os on the sd card and reload your project.

Comment: Can you check for the `xserver` in `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` and make sure there is no `nocursor` in it?